# What is the correct word for moving part of the ground to another place?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to know the correct english word for this 
[activity](https://www.google.nl/search?q=grondverzet&biw=1536&bih=756&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAmoVChMIsrrQh5GGxwIVijkUCh2czgCN#imgrc=_):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excavating. Google seems to be completely agreeing with what I said cause it returned the same image that you posted in the question :P

Comment: Or earthmoving.